# Express - Setting different maxAge for certain files

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a single page application using Express for the backend and AngularJS for the frontend and I'm having some cache problems.

I'm not using express views, only serving files with `express.static` middleware.

My static files are in `public/app` or `public/dist` depending on enviroment (dist has minified files).

```
app.use app.router
app.use express.static(cwd + '/public/' + publicFolder, maxAge: MAX_AGE)
```

When requesting '/', app.router verifies if user is logged in, and if everything is ok then `index.html` is served via `express.static` (I just call `next()` in the controller). If user is not logged in, it gets redirected to `login.html`

My problem is that if I set maxAge, my `index.html` file gets cached and the first request to '/' doesn't go through `router`. I can enter the app even if I'm not logged in.

If I set maxAge to 0, the problem goes away, but I want to cache all my *.js and *.css files.

What is the correct approach to this kind of problems? Start using views? Different `express.static` mount points?

Comment: Very important issue needed in much more loud voice. Can imagine how many people break their heads over this topic. Thanks for good explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always define individual routes without necessarily using views (although view templates aren't a bad idea).  In this way you could define `index.html` just to apply the special case `maxAge`.

Just be sure to put the route ***before*** the static middleware.

If you wanted you could even use [send](https://github.com/visionmedia/send), the same static server that the `static` middleware uses behind the scenes.  Something like:

```
// install send from npm
var send = require("send");

app.get("/index.html", function (req, res) {
  send(req, "/index.html")
    .maxage(0)
    .root(__dirname + "/public")
    .pipe(res);
});
```

Or the more low level stream way, something like:

```
app.get("/index.html", function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0');

  // Note that you'd probably want to stat the file for `content-length`
  // as well.  This is just an example.

  var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
  stream.pipe(res);
});
```